# How to make the a border fit to a canvas and not the width of a parent div?

Tags: html, css

I  have a section of my website where a div holds my `game` and is nested within a div with the class of `body-content`:

```
<div class = "body-content">
    <div id = "game"></div>
</div>
```

The div `game` contains a canvas that is generated by p5.js.

```
var canvas = createCanvas(SCREEN_SIZE, SCREEN_SIZE);
canvas.parent("game");
```

The div `body-content` has css set as such, so to achieve the alignment and margins that I want for the entire body:

```
.body-content {
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
}
```

I want to put a border specifically around the edges of the `game` div with then intent of it following the size of the canvas within:

```
.body-content #game {
    border: solid;
}
```

The resulting border is matching up with the top and bottom of the canvas properly, yet its width is being set to the width of `body-content`.

How can I make the border stick to the width of the canvas and not the width of the parent div?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle demo?

Comment: Why don’t you _apply_ the border to the canvas element to begin with, instead of the container div …?

Comment: @CBroe there is no canvas element in the HTML until the p5.js sketch runs, and even then there is no way to give said canvas an ID so that I could apply CSS to it

Comment: _“and even then there is no way to give said canvas an ID so that I could apply CSS to it”_ - there are numerous other ways to target an element, than just an id ... `.body-content #game canvas { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this line of code to my p5.js sketch:

```
document.getElementById("game").style = "width: " + SCREEN_SIZE + "px";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing): `box-sizing: border-box`

```
.body-content #game {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Or [outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline):

```
.body-content #game {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

Or make a border using [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow):

```
.body-content #game {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px red;
}
```